# Design patterns: data mapper + dependency injection?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, datamapper

I am following [data mapper guide](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Structural/DataMapper/README.html). But it has a model class in the mapper class. So I modified it by using dependency injection.

Model,

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $userId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @param null $id
     * @param null $username
     * @param null $email
     */
    public function __construct($id = null, $username = null, $email = null)
    {
        $this->userId = $id;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $userId
     */
    public function setUserID($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}
```

Mapper,

```
class UserMapper
{
    public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        $resultSet = array(
            array('userid' => 1, 'username' => 'Odysseus', 'email' => 'Odysseus@ithaca.gr'),
            array('userid' => 2, 'username' => 'Penelope', 'email' => 'Penelope@ithaca.gr')
        );

        $entries   = array();

        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $entries[] = $this->mapObject($row);
        }

        return $entries;
    }

    protected function mapObject(array $row)
    {
        $this->model->setUserID($row['userid']);
        $this->model->setUsername($row['username']);
        $this->model->setEmail($row['email']);

        return $this->model;
    }
}
```

Usage,

```
$model = new User();
$mapper = new UserMapper($model);
$users = $mapper->findAll();
print_r($users);
```

Result (which is incorrect),

```
Array
(
    [0] => User Object
        (
            [userId:protected] => 2
            [username:protected] => Penelope
            [email:protected] => Penelope@ithaca.gr
        )

    [1] => User Object
        (
            [userId:protected] => 2
            [username:protected] => Penelope
            [email:protected] => Penelope@ithaca.gr
        )

)
```

But it returns the correct result without dependency injection,

```
protected function mapObject(array $row)
{
    $entry = new User();
    $entry->setUserID($row['userid']);
    $entry->setUsername($row['username']);
    $entry->setEmail($row['email']);

    return $entry;
}
```

Result,

```
Array
(
    [0] => User Object
        (
            [userId:protected] => 1
            [username:protected] => Odysseus
            [email:protected] => Odysseus@ithaca.gr
        )

    [1] => User Object
        (
            [userId:protected] => 2
            [username:protected] => Penelope
            [email:protected] => Penelope@ithaca.gr
        )

)
```

So, how can I use dependency injection **with** data mapper to return the correct result? any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
class UserMapper
{
    protected function mapObject(array $row)
    {
        return new User($row['userid'], $row['username'], $row['email']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't. The only solution is to inject a factory which then creates the model objects, but [as explained in your other question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34702423/664108) this additional level of abstraction is not really necessary here. The data mapper itself is responsible for creating objects.

---

Here is a solution with dependency injection, where you delegate the object creation to a factory. But I am sure, *you ain't gonna need it*. Coupling the data mapper with the model it maps to is a reasonable thing to do in most cases.

```
class UserMapper
{
    public function __construct(UserFactory $userFactory)
    {
        $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
    }

    protected function mapObject(array $row)
    {
        return $userFactory->createUser($row['userid'], $row['username'], $row['email']);
    }
}

interface UserFactory
{
    public function createUser($id, $name, $email);
}

class DefaultUserFactory implements UserFactory
{
    public function createUser($id, $name, $email)
    {
        return new User($id, $name, $email);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks again. but I don't quite understand - do you mean this layer of mapper pattern is not ` really necessary ? inject a factory` - can you give us an example? how a ` factory` should be like?

Comment: The mapper is good, the factory is not necessary. I'll update my answer with an example anyway.

Comment: thanks but i could just simplify the solution you suggested with my edit above. have a look. so what are the differences? thanks!

Comment: The difference is that you don't use the factory. So now you can also remove the constructor with the needless dependency injection and get the solution that I suggested in the first place :)

Comment: thanks. I see what you mean now. I see that same issue with coupling the model in `DefaultUserFactory`. but I think it is what a mapper does as you put it - ` Coupling the data mapper with the model it maps to is a reasonable thing to do in most cases.`. and that is the first place I try to avoid. but I guess I was wrong :)