# Data Mapper - should I use dependency injection?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, datamapper

Should I pass model as an dependency injection in data mapper pattern or should I declare the model inside the mapper class?

```
class Mapper
{
    public function __construct(
        $model
    )
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function mapObject(array $row)
    {
        $this->model->setArticleId($row['article_id']) ;
        $this->model->setTitle($row['title']);
        $this->model->setDescription($row['description']);
        $this->model->setContent(isset($row['content']) ? $row['content'] : null);
        $this->model->setTemplate(isset($row['template']) ? $row['template']['path'] : null);

        return $this->model;
    }
}
```

or:

```
class Mapper
{
    public function mapObject(array $row)
    {
        $model = new Model;
        $model->setArticleId($row['article_id']) ;
        $model->setTitle($row['title']);
        $model->setDescription($row['description']);
        $model->setContent(isset($row['content']) ? $row['content'] : null);
        $model->setTemplate(isset($row['template']) ? $row['template']['path'] : null);

        return $model;
    }
}
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapper should *create* objects, be it by itself or using a factory. Injecting an "empty" object and then always return the same object but with different data does not make much sense.

Should you inject a factory? It's a good idea to separate object creation and object usage. But IMHO the data mapper falls into the object creation category itself, so `$model = new Model` fits perfectly fine.

Another remark: In your first example, you would inject the model with invalid state, i.e. uninitialized. Allowing invalid state can lead to bugs and is good to avoid.

Actually you allow invalid state in your second example as well, at least theoretically. I'd recommend passing the required data via constructor instead of setter to make sure, instances of `Model` are always valid.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 'In your first example, you would inject the model with invalid state, i.e. uninitialized. Allowing invalid state can lead to bugs and is good to avoid.' I don't quite understand this? could you give us an example? thanks!

Comment: If you allow the model to have invalid (empty) properties at any point, you need to check it vor validity everytime you use it, otherwise you can't be sure if it is initialized correctly. There is a good thread over at programmers.SE on the topic: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/261585/should-a-getter-throw-an-exception-if-its-object-has-invalid-state